# Get data from 2 foreach array from 1st array i want to get name and from second Indexes

Tags: arrays, laravel, model-view-controller, foreach, laravel-5.8

I have two Arrays 1st Array give me a role form Roles table and second array give me the data using this role_id key.

When i pass the array to view how can i get Role that is from first foreach().

This is my

SettingController.php

```
 public function index()
  {
    $users = User::with('roles')->get()->all();
    $access_names = AccessName::all();
    $modules = Module::all();
    $entries = Entry::all();
    $general_settings = Setting::all()->first();
    $module_permissions = ModulePermission::get()->toArray();
    $roles = Role::get();
    $num_roles = count($roles);
    $data = 'roles';
    foreach ($roles as $role){
        foreach ($module_permissions as $permissions){
            if($role['id'] == $permissions['role_id']){
                $roles_data[$role['name']][] = $permissions;
            }
        }
    }
    return view('backend.setting.index', compact(['general_settings', 'roles', 'users', 'access_names', 'roles_data','modules','entries']));
}
```

My output of this code is like this

```
Array
(   
    [Admin] => Array
         (
           [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 179
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [role_id] => 1
                    [access_name_id] => 2
                    [module_permission_id] => 1
                    [entry_type] => own
                    [status] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2019-08-22 04:45:14
                    [updated_at] => 2019-08-22 04:45:14
                )
         )

    [User] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 206
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [role_id] => 2
                    [access_name_id] => 1
                    [module_permission_id] => 1
                    [entry_type] => own
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_at] => 2019-08-22 05:09:40
                    [updated_at] => 2019-08-22 05:09:40
                )
         )
)
```

If i can access data from this then very well other wise i make a new array like this from i can access this by a new array that is data so it is easy to check that

I also tried this but this is not working properly

```
    foreach ($roles as $role){
        foreach ($module_permissions as $permissions){
            if($role['id'] == $permissions['role_id']){
                $roles_data[$role['name']][] = $permissions;
                $array['data'] = $roles_data;
            }
        }
    }
```

But If output come like this that is also very good

```
Array
(   
  [data]=>array
       (
          [Admin] => Array
            (
              [0] => Array
                 (
                    [id] => 179
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [role_id] => 1
                    [access_name_id] => 2
                    [module_permission_id] => 1
                    [entry_type] => own
                    [status] => 0
                    [created_at] => 2019-08-22 04:45:14
                    [updated_at] => 2019-08-22 04:45:14
                )
         )

          [User] => Array
            (
              [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 206
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [role_id] => 2
                    [access_name_id] => 1
                    [module_permission_id] => 1
                    [entry_type] => own
                    [status] => 1
                    [created_at] => 2019-08-22 05:09:40
                    [updated_at] => 2019-08-22 05:09:40
                )
         )
      )
)
```

In view i want to do like this.

view.blade.php

```
   if($role->name == 'data['Admin']'){
       //then do this
    }
    elseif($role->name == 'data['User']'){
      // do this
    }
   else{
      // do this
     }
```

And i also want to this dynamic what can i do to make dynamic i not use 'admin' and 'user' because if i have many roles it is difficult to handle.

**Thanks**.................

Comment: Posting here your whole controller function would be helpfull

Comment: @TharakaDilshan i edit this please check this again